# Best way to do calculations and store calulated values to another snowsql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

After loading data into snow sql table, need to do some calculations and store it in a differnet snow sql table.

what is the best way to achieve this?

In copy command I am able to order or select specific column to ingest data but not able to get derived column by simple math while loading data, after loading into temp table what should i use to do to achieve these kind of operations like aggriagtion ... etc

Some examples would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Given table `foobar` containing individual record rows, you could (for example) aggregate by time and store the result into a table `foo` with the following SQL.

```
create or replace table foo (date date, events number, users number);

insert overwrite into foo select event_time::date,count(*),approx_count_distinct(uuid) from foobar group by 1 order by 1 asc;

select * from foo;
```

It would help to see your SQL, but it maybe you just need to use `INSERT` instead of `COPY INTO` since the latter is for "Loads data from staged files."

It is also worth noting that Snowflake stores as metadata some aggregations (counts, min, mix, count distinct, etc), so the aggregation queries can be metadata-only in which case they are very fast and a summary table is unnecessary.